# How to deal with OutOfMemoryError in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, bitmap, client

Server sends images in the form of byte arrays to my android application. In a loop, Each received byte array is converted to bitmap to be displayed in a ImageView. Problem is that my android device(vince) gives `OutOfMemoryError` after sometime(like 2-3 minutes). This is the same case with emulators too. Is there a way i can avoid this error ? Also, I've set largeHeap to true

**Log :**

```
2020-03-31 20:39:28.040 30083-30158/com.rollout.pcremoteclient E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
    Process: com.rollout.pcremoteclient, PID: 30083
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 153632 byte allocation with 105792 free bytes and 103KB until OOM, target footprint 536870912, growth limit 536870912
        at java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Array.java:782)
        at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:78)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1769)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1406)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
        at com.rollout.pcremoteclient.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:30)
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
package com.rollout.pcremoteclient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.SocketHandler;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.43.191",6777);
                    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    while (true) {
                        final byte[] image_bytearr = (byte[])objectInputStream.readObject();
                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inMutable = true;
                        final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image_bytearr, 0, image_bytearr.length, options);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
    public void init(){
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}
```

**ServerSide :**

```
robot = new Robot();
rectangle = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
while (true) {
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] image_byte_arr = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(image_byte_arr);
    }
```

Comment: Stream and save bitmaps in files (they can be temporary), then you can load and scale down those images so they "just fit" the image views to conserve memory. For second step I recommend using [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) library which is almost a staple of android development at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is decrease the image in the server side, because android have a limit of memory ram that can give per application, no matter is your device have 9gb of RAM for example the operating system give you the max amount depending of the device screen resolution.

But in order to decrease locally your memory usage (but you can still get a `OutOfMemoryError`) is compress the local image after parse and also convert these image to a Webp format to reduce even more the final size of the image, the problem with these is the time to process the image

**Conver to Webp (Google image Format) and compress**

```
Bitmap bitmap;
String fileUrl;

//Get your file URL
//fileUrl
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileUrl, null, null);
FileOutputStream out = this.openFileOutput(Utils.getFilenameFromUrl(Utils.getFilenameFromUrl(preview)), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 50, out);
```

Also in your `AndroidManifest.xml` turn on the **Large Heap** usage adding `android:largeHeap="true"` to your `<application>` tag